# error message when trying to intsall software-centre

Tags: software-center

*after running a command on the terminal to install my software centre it gave me an error message that says " E: Unable to locate package software-centre", what do i do from here?, please help as i am new on ubuntu and im using 16.04  *

Comment: I believe it should be `sudo apt install software-center`.  Ubuntu comes default with the Tab pressing where when you are typing in the word if you press the Tab twice it will auto-complete the word.

Answer (score 0):

It is not called software-centre. The package is called `software-center`.
Therefore, the code should be `sudo apt-get install software-center`